# Exercises on using Java API

Tags: java

Is there a tutorial / book / website that teaches you how to use the Java API? So, let say I am already in this website: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/

What are these packages / classes for? Or if I want to manipulate Strings... how do I know to use java.lang.String?

Then if I am in java.lang.String, I see there is the Interface, class and exception summary. I am sure somewhere there is a documentation that explains all of this. Also, I see a field, constructor, method summary... what are these?

Comment: So basically, you want to learn Java, yes?

Answer (score 3):

What you want sounds like the [Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/).

> Also, I see a field, constructor,
>   method summary... what are these?

[Learning the Java Language.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/java/index.html)

You also want to use a more recent reference than 1.4 since lots of things have changed since then: [Java SE 6](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/). (The documentation for SE 7 is still a draft for the moment)